# weird .part files in download folder

Tags: macos

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.3. 
It happens sometimes that there are .part files in my download folder, with the length of 8 characters and 0kB file-size.

Could this be a virus?

Examples I see are like these 2: `3dOsdT+d.part` and `utYYNFFo.part`

Comment: 0 kB would be a very tiny virus... Don't worry. I'm not answering this, as I can't tell you what this actually is.

Comment: What were the last items you've tried to download? If a download is not complete, it will end up with a *partial* download, named with extension .part

Comment: No, partial downloads generally have .download as extension. However, some download managers and perhaps BitTorrent clients will use the .part extension.

Comment: Firefox makes `.part` files while downloading

Answer (score 1):

It's not a virus. The ".part" files are ***partially*** downloaded files seen during a download or seen later if a download has been interrupted.

Once a download completes successfully, the ".part" file will be renamed to the actual name of the downloaded file. Any (older) ".part" file can be deleted and the deletion would not cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

These files will be created by browsers or download utilities even if you cancel the download from the beginning.